# Feature Extraction on geographical dataset Python

Tags: python, feature-extraction

i'm working with a "geographical dataset" and I need to extract such more features for pattern recognition. In the dataset for each trip there are some samples with lat/long, velocity, address, distance ect.. How can I work with this dataset due to extract features? Are there some "state of the art" solutions?

Comment: Please provide more Info: Are you trying to classify based on some attributes in a supervised manner or are you just looking for patterns in your data (unsupervised)? Provide an example of your data and describe how it is interpreted (what do the lat/lon coordinates represent?). What is the overall goal you want to achieve? There are loads of python libraries in the Spatial/ML/DL domains which may or may not help you... If we have an idea of what to do, we can provide how to do it.

Comment: I also recommend you search more and I found a [paper](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/1591/1/012028/pdf) for your question so that you can update yourself concerning the state-of-the-art in this regard.

Comment: I'm just looking for patterns (unsupervised learning). I want to extract some more features to increase the knowledge for pattern recognition methods. An example of a raw of the dataset is like this : street lat/long of the sample velocity(not a mean value but an instant value) weater type of street(urban ect)